# Accumulate number of records in a hourly time range

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I will explain this to the best of my ability.

I have a series of unique dates in the form of DD/MM/YYYY as shown below:

```
const sortDates = [
'14/04/2018',
'12/04/2018',
'10/04/2018',
]
```

and then I have an array of objects with the following information.

```
const bookings = [
  { bookingStart: '2018-04-14 00:30:00' },
  { bookingStart: '2018-04-14 00:42:00' },
  { bookingStart: '2018-04-14 13:35:00' },
  { bookingStart: '2018-04-12 12:30:00' },
];
```

And what i am trying to achieve is finding and grouping data on an hourly basis per day. Example below:

```
const groupedData = [{
  date: '2018-04-14',
  period : {
     startTime: '00:00',
     endTime: '00:59',
     total: 2, //total bookings found 2018/04/14 00:00 -> 00:59
  },
  date: '2018-04-14',
  period : {
     startTime: '01:00',
     endTime: '01:59',
     total: 0,  //total bookings found 2018/04/14 01:00 -> 01:59
  },
  ...etc
}
```

however i am a little stuck. My current code is as follows, and unsure how the return statement should be:

```
const groupData = sortDates.map((date) => {
  for (let i = 0; i <= 23; i += 1) {
    const startTime = new Date(date);
    const endTime = new Date(date);
    startTime.setHours(i);
    startTime.setMinutes(0);
    startTime.setSeconds(0);
    startTime.setMilliseconds(0);
    endTime.setHours(i);
    endTime.setMinutes(59);
    endTime.setSeconds(0);
    endTime.setMilliseconds(0);
    bookings.map((booking) => {
      const dateTime = new Date(booking.bookingStart);
      if (startTime.getTime() >= dateTime.getTime()
      && dateTime.getTime() <= endTime.getTime()) {
        return {
          date: dateTime,
        };
      }
      return null;
    });
  }
  return null;
});
```

Not even sure if is the nicest or fastest way to do it, but how would i do a return in the format i want? any faster alternatives?

Comment: Your groupedData object has duplicate property names.

Comment: The groupedData is an example of returned data in the 3rd piece of code. Its not declared twice. The actual code is at the bottom.

Comment: I'm not saying `groupedData` is declared twice, I'm saying it has duplicate property names - in your second snippet, it's an array with a single object with keys `date`, `period`, `date` again, `period` again. I'm sure you meant each object to be a separate item in the array, right? `[{ date, period }, { date, period }, ...]`

Comment: woops my bad, ur correct :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution using `moment.js`:

```
sortDates.forEach(date => {
  const dateMoment = moment(date, 'DD/MM/YYYY');
  const bookingsOnDate = bookings.filter(b =>
    dateMoment.isSame(b.bookingStart, 'day'),
  );

  const start = moment(dateMoment);
  const end = moment(dateMoment);

  for (let i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
    start.hour(i);
    start.minutes(0);
    end.hour(i);
    end.minutes(59);

    const foundCount = bookingsOnDate.filter(b => {
      const bookingMoment = moment(b.bookingStart);
      return (
        bookingMoment.isSameOrAfter(start) && bookingMoment.isSameOrBefore(end)
      );
    }).length;

    if (foundCount > 0) {
      groupedData.push({
        date: dateMoment.format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
        period: {
          startTime: start.format('HH:mm:ss'),
          endTime: end.format('HH:mm:ss'),
          total: foundCount,
        },
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I would avoid messing with Dates entirely, and just compare strings instead:

```js
const hmsToHM = hms => hms.match(/^\d\d:\d\d/)[0];
const bookings = [
  { bookingStart: '2018-04-14 00:30:00' },
  { bookingStart: '2018-04-14 00:42:00' },
  { bookingStart: '2018-04-14 00:42:22' },
  { bookingStart: '2018-04-14 00:42:44' },
  { bookingStart: '2018-04-14 13:35:00' },
  { bookingStart: '2018-04-14 00:30:55' },
  { bookingStart: '2018-04-12 12:30:00' },
];
const groupedData = bookings.reduce((groupedData, { bookingStart }) => {
  const [date, time] = bookingStart.split(' ');
  const startHourMin = hmsToHM(time);

  const groupedObj = (() => {
    const foundObj = groupedData
      .find(({ date: findGroupDate, period: {startTime }}) => {
        const findStartHourMin = hmsToHM(startTime);
        return findGroupDate === date && findStartHourMin === startHourMin;
      });
    if (foundObj) return foundObj;
    const newObj = { date, period: {
      startTime: startHourMin + ':00',
      endTime: startHourMin + ':59',
      total: 0,
    }}
    groupedData.push(newObj);
    return newObj;  
  })();

  groupedObj.period.total++;
  return groupedData;
}, []);
console.log(groupedData);
```